# Some field names appended with schema name prefix after exporting tables to Dataverse for Teams

Tags: database, ms-access, dataverse

I'm trying to share Access Data by using Dataverse for Teams as my backend.
My front-end would be consists of forms/queries that I created in this local MS Access DB.

Currently, editing data using forms on my local copy of MS Access DB is fine, and any changes get reflected in the online Dataverse tables.

Theoretically, someone else on the same network using the same MS Access DB file should be able to perform the same, but after opening the exact same file on a different computer, error was observed when trying to edit the data.

Upon looking at the linked tables, it seems that the schema name prefix has been appended in some of the fields (weirdly only the Yes/No type). Ex: Was "fieldname1" on my computer but became "crf3a_fieldname1" on the other computer...

Is there any solution that I can employ to override this issue?

I believe the changes in fieldnames are hindering my vba codes to work properly.

Currently not considering other options to build an app with online database as I'm still rather new to programming, so just trying to make the best out of what I'm currently capable of :X

Comment: custom tables and columns (also in Dataverse for Teams) have always a prefix